# Virtual Combo Box in MFC

Tags: mfc

I have 10 CComboBox in a tab page and I want to load 10k data to each combobox?

It is taking more time for the tab page to get loaded.

In MFC how to implement virtual combobox like virtual list control?

I need to set default selection in the combobox on loading tab.

Can you please someone give me some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to populate all 10 comboboxes on the page's `OnInitDialog`? If so, you could subclass the comboboxes and delay populating them until their `SetFocus`. I've done that to good effect in a near identical scenario before.

Comment: acraig5075 offer you a good solution ... another one is to use this control, that use a derived CListCtrl where you can use it as virtual: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1131087/list-combobox-control

Comment: @acraig5075, If I load data on setfocus of combobox then how to set default text for combobox  through SelectString() on OnInitDialog.

Comment: Setting the default selection is a requirement, that's not immediately obvious from reading the question. If you need that, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51665984/edit) your question.

Comment: @flaviu2, In your sample how to set default text for combobox through SelectString() on OnInitDialog.

Comment: @User890: A virtual list control works by loading data on demand. If you require all data to be present up front (so that you can select a certain item *by content*), you will not gain anything over an implementation, that loads all data right away. You're either going to have to adjust your requirements, or live with your dialog being unresponsive on load.

Comment: My immediate reaction is to re-think the basic design. A combobox containing 10K items seems difficult enough to use that it's pretty much abusing your users.

Comment: You can look carefully over that code, and you will find that CListComboBox::SetEditText is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such virtual Combobox in the WinApi, but you have serveral optimizations.

Only load the complete data to the box, if needed. So only when you get the `CBN_DROPDOWN` event you populate the box with all items. Otherwise you just insert the one selected item.
This method has a drawback that cursor up down in a closed combo doesn't work.

Also you can populate the box only when it receives the focus. Also in this case you just populate the box with the current selected item.

The best result you get is using a owner draw combobox, without using `CBS_HASSTRING`. `CB_ADDSTRING` receives a pointer to your data. In `DrawItem` you use this pointer for drawing.

You still need to add 10k items to each box, but there is no string management and the box is real fast without this memory allocations.